# Unable to Work on Imported sbt project on Eclipse Scala Ide

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I Have downloaded couple of projects from github , which are sbt projects, and imported in Scala IDE. But When I try to run them...they are not showing in run configuration.

I think for sbt project there is some another way to import in eclipse.

Please Help.

Attaching the screenshot of the project.

[Screenshot]

Comment: How have you imported it.?

Comment: yes i have imported the project. There are no errors. But no imports are working , when i try to write some code, it doesn't give any suggestions.

Comment: Are the dependencies being resolved?

Comment: no...whatever that is written in build.sbt. i am not able to see those libraries or dependencies in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should convert it to eclipse projects first.

1.you need to add eclipse plguins in your project/plugins.sbt, something like this: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")`

2.run `sbt` In CLI from your peoject fold and type `eclipse`, wait util it successes. Now , you can import it to eclipse (eclipse project needs .project and .classpath the two files)

BTW, `sbt` and `eclipse` command may be a little slow, be patient.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found in  this solution, I am not sure where to put this file plugins.sbt as i cannot see any such file in the imported git project.

Comment: and what if lets say i build the project this way successfully, but later on if i am to add new dependencies inside build.sbt., then again I have to go through the same procedure?

Comment: No then you do not have to go with the same procedure

Comment: one more question Is there any hard rule, that the scala (if i ahve installed in my system) and  that what project is using (scala version) &  scala of scala IDE. All three versions must be same?

Comment: @HromitProdigy  Intellij IDEA can import sbt project without these procedure . But for eclipse, this is the only way i know , could you check if existing a fold named peoject ?

Comment: @HromitProdigy scala IDE version doesn't need the same version. But the other two maybe need to be the same. If you had see get started in scala offical website. you'll know how to start with sbt and using eclipse with scala project

Comment: @HromitProdigy could you paste the git url ?

Comment: @jenkin i haev added the screenshot of current imported project inside eclipse.

Comment: @HromitProdigy did you install sbt in your env ?

Comment: @jenkin for one on the project, yes there is a project folder and inside it there is a file, plugins.sbt.

Comment: @jenkin But why not for other imported projects, Are those prpjects build under IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @jenkin and for thar project addSbtPlugin("com.websudos" % "phantom-sbt" % "1.13.0") -- is written , are you  aware of what Phantom-sbt is ?

Comment: @HromitProdigy  maybe you'll know something if you do it by your hands.

Comment: @HromitProdigy 
1.install sbt  and make sure you can run sbt from cli - 2.download zip from that demo project and run sbt . then you'll see project fold. each plugin has its own use you can google it if you want to know

Comment: @jenkin now i facing Error: Could not find or load main class ?-XX:PermSize=4096m when i type scala or sbt on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, What I Understood is, For Scala SBT Development, IntelliJ is the preferred  IDE. Almost All projects which are hosted on Github have build.sbt in it. Like for Android Development everyone prefers Android Studio. LikeWise for scala use IntelliJ at least for now.